# files such as js, css, img do not appear

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

After clicking the update button, files such as img, css, js are not uploaded on the update page that opens. Can you help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKRG9.png)

**AdminController:**

update operations are done in the Admin controller.

```
@GetMapping("/admin-update-announcement/{id}")
    public ModelAndView updateAnnouncement(@PathVariable("id") Long id, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("view/html/admin/update-announcement");

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String sessionId = (String) session.getAttribute("sessionId");
        User loggedInUser = userRepo.findBySessionId(sessionId);

        modelAndView.addObject("user", loggedInUser);

        Announcement announcement = announcementRepo.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid announcement Id: " + id));

        modelAndView.addObject("announcement", announcement);

        String errorMessage = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("errorMessage");
        if (errorMessage != null) {
            modelAndView.addObject("errorMessage", errorMessage);
            request.getSession().removeAttribute("errorMessage");
        }
        String message = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("message");
        if (message != null) {
            modelAndView.addObject("message", message);
            request.getSession().removeAttribute("message");
        }

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

**update-announcement.html:**

update page.

```
`<div class="card card-primary mx-5 mb-5">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Announcement</h3>
            </div>


            <form th:action="@{/update-announcement/{id}(id=${announcement.id})}" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" th:object="${announcement}">
                <div th:if="${message}" id="alertMessage" class="alert alert-success m-2" role="alert">
                    <p th:text="${message}"></p>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${errorMessage}" id="errorMessage" class="alert alert-danger m-2" role="alert">
                    <p th:text="${errorMessage}"></p>
                </div>

                <style>
          /* CSS for transparent alert */
          #alertMessage, #errorMessage {
            opacity: 0.7; /* Adjust transparency as desired */
            transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
          }
        </style>

                <script>
          // JavaScript to hide the alert message after 5 seconds
          setTimeout(function() {
            var alertMessage = document.getElementById("alertMessage");
            var errorMessage = document.getElementById("errorMessage");
            if (alertMessage) {
              alertMessage.style.opacity = 0;
              setTimeout(function() {
                alertMessage.style.display = "none";
              }, 500);
            }
            if (errorMessage) {
              errorMessage.style.opacity = 0;
              setTimeout(function() {
                errorMessage.style.display = "none";
              }, 500);
            }
          }, 5000);
        </script>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="id">Id</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" placeholder="Enter the id" name="id" th:field="${announcement.id}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="title">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter the Title" name="title" th:field="${announcement.title}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="content">Content</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Content" name="content" th:field="${announcement.content}"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="createdDate">Created Date</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="createdDate" placeholder="Enter the Created Date" name="createdDate" th:field="${announcement.createdDate}">
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
```

**announcement.html:**

update button in this html file.

```
<tr th:each="announcement : ${announcements}">
                        <td th:text="${announcement.title}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${announcement.content}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${announcement.createdDate}"></td>
                        <td>
                            <a th:href="@{/admin-update-announcement/{id}(id=${announcement.id})}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>

                            <form th:action="@{/admin-announcement-delete/{id}(id=${announcement.id})}" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

After clicking the Update button, I want files such as css, js, img to appear.

Comment: It is not clear what are you after - there is no Update button in the HTML template posted.

Comment: For uploading files you will need a HTML element like this: `<input type="file" name="files" accept="*/*">`

Comment: It is in the announcement.html file.

<a th:href="@{/admin-update-announcement/{id}(id=${announcement.id})}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>

Comment: Well. This is an `Edit` button and not `Update` button. Never mind - what is your issue then? Do you want to choose a file for upload?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem was caused by href's in <link>'s. Thanks for your help @Mar-Z